# How to use a calculated derived field in the where clause or orderby clause in firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using a calculated field, say distance which is not in my schema, firestore. It is calculated by calling a function. This works fine. However I need to use this field (distance) to limit or order by the data example:
`.where ('distance', isLessThan :1000)`
or say :
 `.orderBy ('distance')`

.on firestore data.  I tried to use this way however as this 'distance' field does not exist in forestore, it is giving this error:

> 

[FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to fallback implementation
W/System  (15007): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/FirebaseAuth(15007): Notifying id token listeners about user ( juo4UbaWhdVfmfkr8vyyiY5FNNc2 ).

Thanks!

Comment: You should store 'distance' in your Document, otherwise you will get nothing when you query.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. Firestore has no concept of calculated fields and can only filter on values that exist in the database, not on calculated values. Can you show the completely query that you run?

Answer (score 1):

Firestore has no way to perform (custom or otherwise) calculations inside a query. It can only order/filter on values that are physically present in the documents, and in an index.

If you have a use-case where documents are associated with a location, and you want to find documents within a certain area, the common approach is to store a [geohash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) in each document, and then query on that as explained in the documentation on [implement geoqueries on Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries). I gave a pretty detailed explanation of this approach in my talk on [geoquerying on Firebase and Firestore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q).

Comment: Thanks! It seems firebase is different from a relational database where I can easily create or use a derived table, or derived column however saving more data /hash etc is not practical as I am only going to use this info to sort the listview in flutter. So I would keep looking on a different approach through coding.  I would request firebase to enhance such option for future. Appreciate for the talk

Comment: Firestore is indeed not a relational database, but a so-called NoSQL database. If you want a relational database, I recommend searching for a relational database that has the features you want.  If you decide to continue with Firestore, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and also watching [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video)